# Can retag without retag questions privilege

Tags: discussion, retagging, privileges

I was looking at the privileges, and noticed a `Retag Questions` privilege. However, as long as you can edit posts, you can retag, as I have done it.

Bug because someone under 500 rep shouldn't be able to retag a post, though there is the option to remove the privilege as its basically useless and another UI element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Bug because someone under 500 rep shouldn't be able to retag a post, though there is the option to remove the privilege as its basically useless and another ui element.

That's no bug.

Under 500 rep you aren't able to retag a post *unless* someone approves your edit. Here's the difference: With ≥500, you can retag questions as much as you like, without needing peer review. And that's in the meaning of "a privilege". You get to do stuff others can't.

It's the same with [*Edit questions and answers*](https://superuser.com/privileges/edit). It's a privilege because you can freely edit without having to wait for approval.

---

I agree though that the wording on the privileges page could include a sentence that mentions this discrepancy between being able to *suggest* edits and actually making them.

Comment: Ahh. Makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

You're right, in that anyone can edit, but until you have 2K rep, each and every one of your edits has to be peer reviewed and approved. Called `suggested edits`, they go to a queue to be approved or rejected by fellow users and ♦ moderators.

As slhck said, the privilege means that you can retag without needing approval, once you're at or over 500 reputation.  However, you can't edit post bodies or titles until 2K rep.